# INSERT..SELECT in Oracle always fails with "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: oracle, sqlfiddle

I am proficient in SQL-Server and other forms of SQL, but am trying to learn Oracle SQL.  For some reason I cannot get even the simplest form of `INSERT INTO .. SELECT ..` to work, it always fails with "*SQL command not properly ended.*"

Here is my current example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (year INT, id INT, dat DATE, categ VARCHAR(99));

INSERT INTO table1
(year, id, dat, categ)
select year, id, dat, categ from table1 where id=5000 and year=2013;
```

Here's a SqlFiddle of it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4d34/1

I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong here.  I have checked about a dozen other related question here at SO and more than another dozen on Google but all of the answers either don't apply, or don't work.  I have also tried about a million variations of the commands above, nothing seems to work.

Any help *greatly* appreciated.

---

FWIW, I now think that this is just a SQLFiddle problem, as many had contended.

The Oracle User who reported the problem to me with my code, was of course using the full SQL statement, before I had stripped it down to try to isolate the problem.  *That* query had a completely different problem that just happened to report the same error in SQLFiddle.  Specifically, *its* problem was that I was using `As` for table aliases, which apparently are invalid in Oracle (or perhaps, just in the query I had written).

In any event, sincere thanks to all who tried to help me.

Comment: @Linger That generates a "Missing Expression" error.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that script? The web interface from Oracle-XE (Express) does not allow you to run more than one statement as a script. If you *are* using the XE web interface (in the browser) you are better of dumping that right away and use a proper GUI client (e.g. SQL Developer or any other, even SQL*Plus would be better)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Oracle myself, I have to use SQLFiddle right now, so I am not sure how to answer that.  The SQLFiddle tool does seem to allow both DDL and multiple DMLs for all other cases I have tried.  (I welcome any cheap way to get Oracle on my desktop, a'la SQL Server's Developer Edition).

Comment: works just fine for me.  In SQL Developer (free IDE from Oracle), put that into a SQL Worksheet and hit F5 (Run script).

Comment: get Oracle XE [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html)

Comment: @tbone I have to work through SQLFiddle right now.  I don't think that its a problem unique to SQLFiddle because it was reported to me by an Oracle user trying to use one of my SQL statements.

Comment: This is not a general Oracle problem (your script works just fine in my SQL client). And it *does* work in SQLFiddle if you use the insert in the panel on the left hand side: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5678/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I understand and that's fair, I'd probably say the same about a SQL Server problem I could only reproduce in SQLFiddle...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a problem in SQLFiddle and not a programming or an Oracle/SQL problem

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Technically, its still on-topic as SQLFiddle counts as a software development tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (year INT, id INT, dat DATE, categ VARCHAR(99))
/

INSERT INTO table1
(year, id, dat, categ)
select year, id, dat, categ from table1 where id=5000 and year=2013
```

This works, that is, if you paste both statements in the left (schema) window in SQL fiddle. I  dont' think SQL Fiddle allows `insert..select` in the SQL window at all.

Comment: SQLFiddle does allow INSERTS in the SQL window.  `INSERT..VALUES(..)` works just fine.  And `INSERT..SELECT..` works for other DBMSs in SQLFiddle.

Comment: And ";" *is* the chosen separator in both of my SQLFiddle windows of my example.

Comment: Be that as it may: the statement works in the left window, while in the right window it fails, even without the semicolon.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - as others have pointed out, INSERT...SELECT... in the right panel in an Oracle SQLFiddle fails. Move it to the left panel (see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8bd53/1)) and it works fine. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19b56)

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (year INT, id INT, dat DATE, categ VARCHAR(99))
//

INSERT INTO table1 (year, id, dat, categ)
SELECT year, id, dat, categ 
FROM table1 
WHERE id = 5000 AND year=2013
//
```

Comment: This just generate more errors: "Missing or invalid option" after the first and "Missing Expression" after the second.

Comment: Your SQLfiddle, has everything in the Build-Schema window, so it never executes the INSERT..SELECT in the Run SQL window.

Comment: OK, the "Missing or invalid option" error on the `CREATE TABLE` was cleared by changing the "statement terminator" dropdown option on SQLFiddle.  But the original error remains when I try to execute your `INSERT` in the RunSQL window.

Comment: On that is not the problem one can select and insert data into same table.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are facing this problem but there is no issue with syntax

I think it is just how you are executing the query on fiddle i just changed the execution flow and moved Insert statement in schema build section then the whole thing worked fine without changing a word (but i have inserted some sample data to show the exact working)

see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38e62/1